# Passing DataSet to WCF Service

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0

I am new to .NET.  I am trying to pass the `DataSet` following way to WCFService.

```
public static System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
wscfservice.wcftestfunction(string1, string2, ref ds);
```

in WSDL file,  the type defined

```
ActualType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" Name="DataSet" Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"
```

If I don't use `ref`, I am getting the compilation error. After running the program, I am getting a null value.

Here are error and `ds` descriptions

```
Channel Obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context.
```

- ds  {System.Data.DataSet}   System.Data.DataSet
      CaseSensitive   false   bool
      Container   null    System.ComponentModel.IContainer
      DataSetName "NewDataSet"    string
- DefaultViewManager  {System.Data.DataViewManager}   System.Data.DataViewManager
      DesignMode  false   bool
      EnforceConstraints  true    bool
- Events  {System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList}    System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList
- ExtendedProperties  Count = 0   System.Data.PropertyCollection
      HasErrors   false   bool
      IsInitialized   true    bool
- Locale  {en-US} System.Globalization.CultureInfo
      Namespace   ""  string
      Prefix  ""  string
- Relations   {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataSetRelationCollection}  System.Data.DataRelationCollection {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataSetRelationCollection}
      RemotingFormat  Xml System.Data.SerializationFormat
      SchemaSerializationMode IncludeSchema   System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode
      Site    null    System.ComponentModel.ISite
- Tables  {System.Data.DataTableCollection}   System.Data.DataTableCollection
      Count   0   int
      IsReadOnly  false   bool
      IsSynchronized  false   bool
- List    Count = 0   System.Collections.ArrayList
- SyncRoot    {System.Data.DataTableCollection}   object {System.Data.DataTableCollection}
- Static members
- Non-Public members
- Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

Comment: 1.  Don't use `DataSet` - make a classes that represent the data and pass them in.  2.  I'd have to check, but I'm pretty certain that the `ref` keyword can't be used in WCF.   On a more general note, do you get an error when you try to compile or run this code?

Comment: I am able to compile and not able to run.I added error description to my question.Thank you

Comment: If you must use `DataSet`, you need to set the `Name` property, otherwise it will not serialize.

Comment: I would agree with Tim. Do not pass datasets as arguments to a WCF service. Even if you manage to make it work, you will suffer intense pain owning and maintaining this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to (or must) use a `DataSet`, you need to set the `Name` property in order to ensure it serializes.

```
public static System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet("MyDataSet");
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A name for the DataSet is required to ensure that the XML
>   representation of the DataSet always has a name for the document
>   element, which is the highest level element in a schema definition.